# Password is correct, yet I get an incorrect password error

Tags: php, authentication

Heres my script, no matter what I do I keep getting incorrect password, please help!

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email-field'];
$password = $_POST['password-field'];

if ($email&&$password){ 
   $connect = mysql_connect("xx","xx","xx") or die("Couldnt connect!");
   mysql_select_db(xx) or die("Couldnt find db");

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
   $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); 
   if ($numrows!=0){
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $dbemail = $row['email'];
        $dbemail = $row['password'];
     }

  if ($username==$dbusername&&$md5password==md5($password)) {
      echo "You're in!";
  }else
      echo "Incorrect password";    
}
else
    die("That user doessnt exist!");
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password"); 

?>
```

Comment: are you sure your account has permissions from your IP to even connect?

Comment: Tip: Preview the question before submitting it. It helps avoid major errors, like, uh, well, the script not appearing.

Comment: Thanks Kendall.And what do you mean mike?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Also , using MD5 to encrypt passwords is a sad joke. You should be using either `crypt()` with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`  or PBKDF2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dbemail = $row['email'];
$dbemail = $row['password'];
```

You call those 2 both $dbemail. While in your if statement, you use $dbusername and $md5password.

You should change $row['email'] to $dbusername and $row['password']to $md5password.

```
$dbusername = $row['email'];
$md5password = $row['password'];
```

Comment: This isn't a text conversation; please don't use ”u”...this of for professional help in a professional atmosphere. Proper English only.

Comment: Sorry man, in dutch ( my native language ) U is very respectful so I make that mistake quite often.

Comment: No worries friend. Just want to make sure its easy and understandable for everyone; while keeping it professional.

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `$dbusername` nor `$password`.

Comment: What do you mean?
Total noob here

Comment: You put $dbemail as the username and the password. So basically $password will ALWAYS with no exception equal null :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning dbemail twice rather than md5password.